# Open, Launch or Show a file for the user to read or write in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms, file-io

It sounds very simple but I have searched and cannot seem to find a way to open a log file which the user just created from my windows form app. The file exits I just want to open it after it is created.

I have a `Dim path As String = TextBox1.Text` and once the user names and clicks ok on the savefiledialog I have a msgbox that says "Done" and when you hit OK I have tried this

`FileOpen(FreeFile, path, OpenMode.Input)` but nothing happens. I just want it to open the log and show it to the user so they can edit or save it again or anything.

This is where I got the above code.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.filesystem.fileopen.aspx

Searching is difficult because everyone is trying to "Open" a file and process it during runtime. I am just trying to `Show` a file by `Launching` it like someone just double clicked it.
Here is the entire Export Button click Sub. It basically writes listbox items to file.

```
Private Sub btnExport_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnExport.Click

    Dim sfd As New SaveFileDialog
    Dim path As String = TextBox1.Text
    Dim arypath() As String = Split(TextBox1.Text, "\")
    Dim pathDate As String
    Dim foldername As String
    foldername = arypath(arypath.Length - 1)

    pathDate = Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd") & "_" & Now.ToString("hh;mm")
    sfd.FileName = "FileScannerResults " & Chr(39) & foldername & Chr(39) & " " & pathDate

    sfd.InitialDirectory = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal)
    sfd.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv"
    sfd.ShowDialog()

    path = sfd.FileName

    Using SW As New IO.StreamWriter(path)

        If CkbxFolder.Checked = True Then
            SW.WriteLine("Folders")
            For Each itm As String In ListBox1.Items
                SW.WriteLine(itm)
            Next
        End If

        If CkbxFiles.Checked = True Then
            SW.WriteLine("Files")
            For Each itm As String In ListBox2.Items
                SW.WriteLine(itm)
            Next
        End If

    End Using
    MsgBox("Done...")
    FileOpen(FreeFile, path, OpenMode.Input) 'Why can't I open a file for you...

End Sub
```

Comment: FileOpen don't show anything for you, just opens the file, now it is up to you read the contents and show it in a multiline textbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use the old VB6 methods. They are still here for compatibility reason, the new code should use the more powerful methods in the System.IO namespace.

However, as said in comments, FileOpen don't show anything for you, just opens the file

You coud write

```
Using  sr = new StreamReader(path)
    Dim line = sr.ReadLine()
    if !string.IsNullOrEmpty(line) Then
       textBoxForLog.AppendText(line)
    End If
End Using
```

or simply (if the file is not too big)

```
Dim myLogText = File.ReadAllText(path)
textBoxForLog.Text = myLogText
```

As alternative, you could ask the operating system to run the program associated with the file extension and show the file for you

```
Process.Start(path)
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it was easy.

Answer (score 1):

To get the same behavior as if the user double-clicked it, just use `System.Diagnostics.Process`, and pass the filename to it's `Start` method:

```
Process.Start(path)
```

This will open the file using whatever the default application is for that filename based on its extension, just like Explorer does when you double-click it.